# Compile time lifetime checks

Tags: c++

So you have object `x` of type `X` and object y of type `Y`.  `X` and `Y` are related and it is required that `y` be destroyed before its related `x`.

In other words, something like so:

```
struct X { void do_something(); }
struct Y
{
    Y(X&x) : my_x(&x) {}
    void do_something() { my_x->do_something(); }
private:
    X * my_x;
};
```

Being a defensive programmer you'd like to use a smart pointer for `my_x` above.  However, so far as I know, there's no appropriate pointer.  This pointer would need to know that it does not own its raw pointer and that it should not outlive the object it points to.

I think for the most part this would be impossible to show at compile time.  However, in some cases it could be provable that `y` inappropriately outlives its `x`.

Can you think of any way to create a compile time error when this is the case or are we stuck with a runtime assertion?

Comment: Since the scope of lifetime cannot be determined by static analysis, hard to imagine a compile-time enforcement.

Comment: If you you need sequencing guarantees your runtime doesn't already provide, do your own sequencing.

Comment: What do you mean by destroyed? Could you just destroy the related `X` as the last statement in `Y`'s destructor?

Comment: "This pointer would need to know that it does not own its raw pointer and that it should not outlive the object it points to." What about a custom deleter? Or a `weak_ptr`?

Comment: Two cases come to my mind how you could (syntactically) create a situation where `x` outlives `y`: `Y y(...); {X x; y = x;}` (copy-assignment) and `Y* y; {X x; y = new Y(x);}` (`*y` is an object of dynamic storage duration). You could prevent those two.

Comment: So.. a weak-reference.

Answer (score 1):

Does this not solve your problem? It ensures that the related `Y` is always destroyed before the `X`.

```
struct X;

struct Y
{
    Y(X& x) : my_x(&x) {}
    void do_something() { my_x->do_something(); }
private:
    X* my_x;
};

struct X
{
    X() : owned_y_(this) { }
    void do_something();
private:
    Y owned_y_;
};
```

Comment: `X` presumably is useful in general, and not just with `Y`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this

```
struct X { void do_something(); }
struct Y
{
    Y(X&x) : my_x(&x) {}
    void do_something() { my_x->do_something(); }
private:
    X * my_x;
 };


struct XY_Holder{
    X x_;
    Y y_;
    XY_Holder():x_{},y_{&x_}{}
};
```

The x_ and y_ objects will be constructed in order or declaration and destructed in reverse order, thus the compiler ensures that y_ will not outlast x_